I don't get a notification for compliance change status from aws config
I have tried to to code via cdk an email notification if compliance status of managed rule "maxAccessKeyAge" is non_compliant. I have followed this guide: https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/config-resource-non-compliant
Unfortunately I don't get any e-mail when the compliant status changed. I don't register any invocations if I look at the monitoring dashboards from my event bus.
This is the event pattern of my event bridge rule:
{
  "detail-type": ["Config Rules Compliance Change"],
  "detail": {
    "configRuleName": ["access-keys-rotated"],
    "messageType": ["ComplianceChangeNotification"],
    "newEvaluationResult": {
      "annotation": ["IAM Access Keys are not rotated within an year."],
      "complianceType": ["NON_COMPLIANT"]
    },
    "resourceType": ["AWS::IAM::AccessKey"]
  },
  "source": ["aws.config"]
}

This is my code to create the "monitoring-infra"
def access_keys_rotated(self, sns_topic: Topic):
    managed_rule = ManagedRule(
        self,
        id="access-keys-rotated",
        identifier=ManagedRuleIdentifiers.ACCESS_KEYS_ROTATED,
        config_rule_name=
            "access-keys-rotated",
        description="Checks if active IAM access keys are rotated within an year.",
        input_parameters={"maxAccessKeyAge": 350},
        maximum_execution_frequency=MaximumExecutionFrequency.TWENTY_FOUR_HOURS,
    )
    event_rule = Rule(
        self,
        id="access-keys-rotated-eventrule",
        event_bus=EventBus.from_event_bus_name(
            scope=self,
            id="iam-compliance-rules-akr",
            event_bus_name="eventbus",
        ),
        event_pattern=EventPattern(
            source=["aws.config"],
            detail_type=["Config Rules Compliance Change"],
            detail={
                "messageType": ["ComplianceChangeNotification"],
                "configRuleName": [managed_rule.config_rule_name],
                "resourceType": ["AWS::IAM::AccessKey"],
                "newEvaluationResult": {
                    "complianceType": ["NON_COMPLIANT"],
                    "annotation": [
                        "IAM Access Keys are not rotated within an year."
                    ],
                },
            },
        ),
    )
    event_rule.add_target(
        targets.SnsTopic(
            sns_topic,  # type: ignore
            retry_attempts=2,
        )
    )

In the console everything looks like I assume. I have subscribed the sns topic via email. The event pattern looks correct for me.
Does anyone have a clue what I am doing wrong? I am thankful for every hint in the correct direction.

It worth taking a closer look at how you are setting the permission for EventBridge publishing to the topic.
Normally you have 3 options when an AWS service is working with another AWS service:

Resource policy, the target service allows particular action based on the permissions you defined allowing the source service (doing some action).
Service Linked Role policy, which is managed by AWS and allows the service to perform common tasks that are commonly needed. Not all services use this approach.
Customer managed role (most common), requiring you to create the role (either manually or during initial setup of the service in the console).

This link explains how to add a resource policy to allow EventBridge publish to topic: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-use-resource-based.html#eb-sns-permissions
